# Spotify SDK iOS token exchange service

Tags: ios, xcode, heroku, spotify

I have to implement Spotify SDK on an iOS app, but I don't understand how can I deploy the token exchange service on my website..
I've tried with Heroku but I don't understand how to prepare the app, I've add the Gemfile but I receive always the error "no Cedar-supported app detected"